# JAWS not reading the screen automatically after windows is launched

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I am using JAWS 2023, JAWS is not reading the contents of the webpage when I launch the application, I know we can use sayAll command but as per my requirement JAWS has to read the contents on webpage automatically upon its launch without any external action. Is there a way we can force the JAWS to read the contents automatically upon launch. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that option turned on?  Bring up the "Settings Center" (<kbd>Ins</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then "Utilities", then "Settings Center").

Navigate the tree to "Web/HTML/PDFs", expand it, then navigate to "Reading". Expand "Reading" and there should be an item called "Document and Web Pages Automatically Read When Loaded".  Make sure it's enabled.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/76714/slugolicious @slugolicious Thanks for the response. The above option is enabled but still I see that JAWS is not reading the contents until click the screen

Comment: Is the browser the active window? You said click in it, making it sound like the browser might not be the active window. Can you provide more details on “launching the application”? Are you in the browser and you type a new URL in the address area? Then your page loads and does not announce? Or are you launching the browser from another app? It sounds like JAWS **is** reading the webpage as soon as it has focus?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am actually referring to desktop application. This issue is happening when I am trying to launch Desktop application. JAWS doesn't read the contents on the screen until I click with my mouse.